# What is 'Oracle’s SQL:2011 dialect'?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am a beginner for Oracle SQL and trying to do an assignment.
I want to know the brief explanation of

> '**Oracle’s SQL:2011 dialect**'

In one of my assignments, it says,

> '**create an object-relational database (ORDB) schema using Oracle’s SQL:2011 dialect**'

Are they asking to create the underlying database with '**Oracle database 11g**'?

Comment: There is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) about SQL:2011 ,the standard is nothing but implementation and support of temporal database.12c was in full compliance and pretty much 10g and 11g supported some of the features.

Comment: See also [Oracle Compliance To Core SQL:2011](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_standard_sql003.htm#SQLRF55516)

Answer (score 1):

I've been around for a while now, and never heard of "Oracle SQL: 2011 dialect". Google doesn't know either.

I'm, though, pretty much sure it isn't about 11g as it was released in 2007. **No** major version was released in 2011:

- 11gR2 in 2009
- 12cR1 in 2013

so I'd suggest you to ask person (who gave you that assignment) to explain what they meant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind response.

Comment: You're welcome. If you ever find out what it is, please, let us know.

Comment: @Littlefoot: maybe they are referring to Oracle's support (or variation) of the SQL:2011 standard?